# How to find out if an index is aligned

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, scripting

I'm struggling to find any confirmation within sql server or sql management studio that my index is in fact aligned with my partition.

I'm creating a primary key constraint on a partitioned table:

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [pfDATA](bigint) AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (0);
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [psDATA] AS PARTITION pfDATA TO ([P_CURRENT], [P_CURRENT]);
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DATA](
    [DATAID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [VALUE1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [VALUE2] [int] NOT NULL,
    [VALUEetc] [int] NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PK_DATA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [DATAID] ASC
    ) ON psDATA(DATAID)
) ON psDATA(DATAID);
```

SQL management studio doesn't seem to give me any feedback visually about the characteristics of this index.

What I normally do when the application doesn't tell me what I need to know visually, is let the application generate a CREATE script (for the key/index or table, it doesn't matter in this case). What I expect to see is the partition scheme being mentioned in the constraint clause, but what I get is no mention of any partitioning:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DATA](
    [DATAID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [VALUE1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [VALUE2] [int] NOT NULL,
    [VALUEetc] [int] NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PK_DATA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [DATAID] ASC
    )
);
```

Is there any way to check if my indexes are constructed correctly (and are in fact, aligned)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to see partitions in scripted objects.
All you need to do is to go to Tools-Options-Scripting and play with checkboxes there:
[image]

Comment: Didn't expect the solution to be this easy - maybe that explains exactly why I couldn't find anything about it. Enabled script indexes and partition schemes and now my script is output as expected.